# Assign a certain value to all other values if at least one criteria per value is met

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2675ae91c06041db6acd9a0754aa6815)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_status VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(campaign, country, sales_status, quantity
)
VALUES 
("C001", "DE", "demand", "100"),
("C001", "US", "shipped", "300"),
("C001", "NL", "shipped", "700"),
("C001", "FR", "shipped", "400"),

("C002", "DE", "demand", "500"),
("C002", "US", "demand", "900"),
("C002", "FR", "shipped", "200"),

("C003", "US", "demand", "600"),
("C003", "NL", "demand", "250"),
("C003", "FR", "demand", "150"),
("C003", "PL", "demand", "550"),

("C004", "DE", "shipped", "825"),
("C004", "PL", "shipped", "462");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
campaign    sales_status    SUM(quantity)
C001          shipped             1500
C002          shipped             1600
C003          demand              1550
C004          shipped             1287
```

---

In the above result I want that the `sales_status` per campaign is `shipped` in case there is **at least one country per campaign** in which the `sales_status` is `shipped`.

For example in campaign `C002` only `FR` is `shipped` so in the result `C002` should be in `shipped`.

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
campaign,
(CASE WHEN MAX(sales_status = 'shipped') OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) = 1
THEN 'shipped' ELSE sales_status END) AS sales_status,
SUM(quantity)
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, it does not give me the correct result. 
What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: your code seems overly complicated for what you state you wish to achieve.

Comment: `OVER (PARTITION BY campaign)` makes no sense - you already have GROUP BY by this column. So aggregate version of MAX() is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  campaign,
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN sales_status = 'shipped' THEN sales_status END), 
    MAX(sales_status)
  ) sales_status,
  SUM(quantity) total
FROM operations
GROUP BY campaign;
```

Or with window functions `FIRST_VALUE()` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  campaign,
  FIRST_VALUE(sales_status) OVER (PARTITION BY campaign ORDER BY sales_status = 'shipped' DESC) sales_status,
  SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) total
FROM operations
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ecb99e55c6ffcb27a126fc1603396b4f).
Results:

```
> campaign | sales_status | total
> :------- | :----------- | ----:
> C001     | shipped      |  1500
> C002     | shipped      |  1600
> C003     | demand       |  1550
> C004     | shipped      |  1287
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple

```
SELECT
campaign,
MAX(sales_status) AS sales_status,
SUM(quantity)
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1;
```

?

If there can be another `sales_status` values you may use something like

```
SELECT
campaign,
CASE WHEN SUM(sales_status = 'shipped') 
     THEN 'shipped'
     ELSE 'demand' 
     END AS sales_status,
SUM(quantity)
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4d9db39458836d704684032de89b10d5)